# Change HTML Structure of Transaction E-Mail

Tags: magento-1.9, email

I need to change the HTML structure of the E-Mail template for the "New Order E-Mail".

However I only see the tag `{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}` in the Template. How/where can I change what that tag generates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below file

```
app/design/frontend/default/your-theme/layout/sales.xml
```

And find below code

```
<sales_email_order_items>
    <block type="sales/order_email_items" name="items" template="email/order/items.phtml">
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_default</block><template>email/order/items/order/default.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_grouped</block><template>email/order/items/order/default.phtml</template></action>
        <block type="sales/order_totals" name="order_totals" template="sales/order/totals.phtml">
            ...
            ...
        </block>
    </block>
</sales_email_order_items>
```

this code call this file

> app/design/frontend/default/your-theme/template/email/order/items.phtml

if above file not fount in your theme then please check on base theme

> app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items.phtml

Here you can change HTML structure if the email template